# Python Gtk3 right click menu

Tags: python, gtk, gobject

I am trying to create a pop-up menu in python/gtk3. So far I have tried the following code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
def show_menu(self, *args):     
    menu = Gtk.Menu()
    i1 = Gtk.MenuItem("Item 1")
    menu.append(i1)
    i2 = Gtk.MenuItem("Item 2")
    menu.append(i2)
    i2.show()    
    i1.show()
    menu.popup(None, None, None, None, 0, Gtk.get_current_event_time())
    print("Done")


window = Gtk.Window() 
button = Gtk.Button("Create pop-up") 
button.connect("clicked", show_menu) 
window.add(button) 
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

but the popup menu doesn't show up? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `menu` is a local variable in the `show_menu()` function, and it is not referenced by anything else, its reference count drops to 0 and it gets destroyed at the end of the function; unfortunately, that is right when you are expecting to see it.

Instead, create `menu` in the global scope which makes it so that `menu` isn't local to one function anymore, and so it won't get destroyed at the end of the function.

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

def show_menu(self, *args):
    i1 = Gtk.MenuItem("Item 1")
    menu.append(i1)
    i2 = Gtk.MenuItem("Item 2")
    menu.append(i2)
    menu.show_all()
    menu.popup(None, None, None, None, 0, Gtk.get_current_event_time())
    print("Done")

window = Gtk.Window()
button = Gtk.Button("Create pop-up")
menu = Gtk.Menu()
button.connect("clicked", show_menu)
window.connect('destroy', Gtk.main_quit)
window.add(button)
window.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: thank you, I thought the problem was about Gtk. Appearently, it is not.

Answer (score 1):

In the callback, do `menu.attach_to_widget (widget, None)`.  Instead of *args it may be simpler to just supply the right arguments to the callback as well, which I believe in this case would just be be `show_menu(self, widget, user_data)'.

The attach_to_widget basically passes responsibility for the menu to the GtkWindow, including all cleanup, positioning, etc..